# Salesforce Chatbot : use NLP when the bot ask Question

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-einstein

I have setup a chatbot for my customer.
For that, I have configured the bot with different dialogs and pattern to help them going to the response they seek. I also have activated the Einstein bot intent (Natural Language Processing : NLP) to let them type answer to get directly to the right dialogs.

But it's here that I have a problem. When I set a dialog with a question (with or without choices) when I write an NPL answer, the bot stop and wait another input.

**Exemple**: the bot asks "Are you ok?" if I respond "Agent" (word link to another dialog) the bot stop and if I rewrite "Agent" the bot start the dialogs "Agent".

Dialog config : [Dialog config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhIg8.png)

Chat exemple : [Chat exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRzfU.png)

I don't know why it's happening or how can I resolve this. I have read the documentation but nothing link to this problem.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issues. It comes from the entity that we were using. The entity was set with a standard text. So, when a user was writing some text (utterance values or not) it was store and that was good for the bot.

The solution was to create an entity of Value type. Write in it the Buttons label. Like this if a user clicks on the button or write the button label, it can be stored and go further, if not it will go on the intent recognition. And finally, if all the 2 fails, the bot goes in the conversation repair.

[Here is a process Schema draw by a salesforce member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUa7E.png)